# how to create an app using the functions in other apps

Tags: android

I need ur help..!

I m creating an app in android. The apps use the functions in the other apps which are already present. I want my app to be standalone. I can't use the functions in those app.

To be more clear, If i create an app for making video calls. The app needs to use the functions in the phone apps. can i just create an instance and use the functions or should i redo all the functions which are required?

It will be helpful if i get to know what will happen wen the app is inserted in the code base and compiled.? where ll the R.java file get created?

Could u suggest me some links to get a detail info about it?

Answer (score 1):

developer.android.com is really useful when it comes to explaining the various features of android development, as well as some great code samples.
When you say you are using the functions of other apps, are you using intents or checking if the app is installed?
If there is an app that has the functionality you need, you can always set a home page that tells the user that these apps will be needed or change your application so it uses the features in android and not the third party apps.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If the apps don't provide an API or intent-filter for what you want to do, you cannot include/integrate them easily.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a license to use components from the other apps and have access to their source code, you are going to have to re-implement the functionality you need from scratch or from a combination of available platform capabilities, libraries, and appropriately licensed example code.

(If you were content to leverage exported capabilities of other apps that had actually been installed on the device, you could do some things via intents.  But you seemed to say this was not acceptable, that you needed to take capability from apps that would not be installed.)